# Beta reduction in lambda calculus using Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I have defined the following functions for beta reduction but i'm not sure how to consider the case where free variables get bounded.

```
data Term = Variable Char | Lambda Char Term | Pair Term Term deriving (Show,Eq)
--substition
s[M:x]= if (s=x) then M else s
AB[M:x]= (A[M:x] B [x:M])
Lambda x B[M:x] = Lambda x B 
Lambda y P[M:x]= if x=y then Lambda y P else Lambda y P (M:x) 



--beta reduction
Reduce [s]= s
Reduce[Lambda x B]M = B[M:x]
Reduce[L1 L2] = (Reduce [L1] Reduce [L2])
```

Answer (score 4):

The link *hammar* gave in the comment describes the solution in detail.

I'd just like to offer a different solution. [Nicolaas Govert de Bruijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaas_Govert_de_Bruijn), a Dutch mathematician, invented an [alternative notation for lambda terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index). The idea is that instead of using symbols for variables, we use numbers. We replace each variable by the number representing how many lambdas we need to cross until we find the abstraction that binds the variable. Abstraction then don't need to have any information at all. For example:

```
λx. λy. x
```

is converted to

```
λ λ 2
```

or

```
λx. λy. λz. (x z) (y z)
```

is converted to

```
λ λ λ 3 1 (2 1)
```

This notation has several considerable advantages. Notably, since there are no variables, there is no renaming of variables, no α-conversion. Although we have to renumber the indices accordingly when substituting, we don't have to check for names conflicts and do any renaming. The above Wikipedia article gives an example of how a β-reduction works with this notation.

Comment: It seems the link you're referring to has disappeared. Would you happen to remember what link this is?

Comment: @hammar Do you happen to remember?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Unfortunately not, all I could suggest now is to search online. If I remember/find, I'll add it here.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I ended up just implementing de Bruijn indices after all, but am still interested in seeing how it would proceed for "normal" variables.